# Append Date to a table name in Proc

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I created a function to get me a value of the current date in yyyymmdd format.

```
create or replace function currdate() returns text as $$ select 'account_'||TO_CHAR(current_date , 'yyyymmdd');
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Now i have to write a Proc to append this date 'yyyymmdd' to a create a snapshot table that will be created on the 1st and last day of the month.
I wrote the below Proc

```
create or replace procedure proc_1() AS $$
declare 
dttoday text := currdate();
int_check int := checkint(); 
begin 
if int_check = 1 then 
create table **schema.snapshot_currdate** as (select * from schema1.original_table); end if;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Here when the table is created : **snapshot_currdate** I need it to be created as name **snapshot_yyyymmdd** (Date it was executed)
Declared Variable int_check is a function that checks if its 1st or last day of the month it will return integer value 1

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, Postgres 9.1 is four years past EOL.
Something like:

```
currdate() returns text as $$ select 'account_'||TO_CHAR(current_date , 'yyyymmdd');
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.proc_1()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
dttoday text := currdate();
begin
EXECUTE 'create table '|| quote_ident('public')||'.'||quote_ident('snapshot_'||split_part(dttoday, '_', 2))||'()';
RAISE NOTICE '%', dttoday;
end;
$procedure$
```

The `split_part` is because  `currdate()` returns `account_yyyymmdd` and you say you want `snapshot_yyyymmdd`. For more information on dynamic commands see here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for your response.
One qq: your EXECUTE statement says to create the table but how do i say where to get it from, i mean from clause

If i replace the Currdate() to just get 'yyyymmdd'
create or replace function archive.currdate() returns text as $$ select TO_CHAR(current_date , 'yyyymmdd'); 
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

Comment: If you change `currdate()` then you don't need `split_part`, just `quote_ident('snapshot_'||dttoday)`.  Add `as (select * from schema1.original_table)` to end of statement after removing '()'.

Comment: I chnaged Currdate output to be 'yyyymmdd' and updated Proc


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_1()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
dttoday text := currdate();
begin
EXECUTE 'create table '|| quote_ident('schema')||'.'||quote_ident('snapshot_'||dttoday) as (select * from table1);
RAISE NOTICE '%', dttoday;
end;
$procedure$

but looks like a get error at the Select * from

Comment: || ' as (select * from table1)'. You are building a string. Read the doc link I posted.

Comment: Thank u so much for guiding me through this